# WCF app.config for release and for test

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, web-config, app-config

For example in `Web.config` it is possible to have `Web.Release.config`

where is some database connection defined like:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <!-- live db connection -->
</connectionStrings>
```

and `Web.Test.config` with:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <!-- test db connection -->
</connectionStrings>
```

**Question**: is is possible to make the similar construction for `app.config` to consume different Services depending on build target?

**Background information:** if I use *Add Service Reference...* in Visual Studion than some URL is used and it generate
endpoints:

```
<endpoint address />
```

To switch to other endpoint I have to change app.config manually or generate new Service Reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a plugin to visual studio called [SlowCheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) that add config transform capabilities to `app.config` files, just the same way as it works for `web.config`. It's very useful - I don't understand why it isn't included as default functionality in Visual Studio.